# How possibly HTML files to retrieve database from MYSQL (using php on the server)?

Tags: php, html, ajax, database, mysqli

I want to create form in HTML files. let say it calls index.html ( client will see this page), and the HTML will be included some ajax codes where it links to php (server connect to Mysql)

So that client can do (insert delete edit) to database by inserting form in the index.html. How possibly to do that?. Please give me a simple code so that I can learn. Thank you so much. I found that PHP can link to others php to retrieve the data. But I would love to use HTML instead ,to link to php on the server.

Thank you so much.

edited code

```
enter code here (this is index.html)
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit Form Using AJAX PHP and javascript</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script>
   function myFunction() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&email1=' + email + '&password1=' + password + '&contact1=' + contact;
if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || contact == '')
{
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
//AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://../test2.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
return false;
}</script>

</head>
<body> 
    <div id="mainform">
        <div class="innerdiv">
            <h2>Submit Form</h2>
            //div starts here

            <form id="form">
                <h3>Fill Your Information!</h3>
                <div>
                    <label>Name :</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" id="name" /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Email :</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" id="email"/><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="password" id="password" /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Contact No :</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" id="contact" /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="button" id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="clear"></div>
        </div>            
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php.

```
//Fetching Values from URL  
$name2 = $_POST['name1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email1'];
$password2 = $_POST['password1'];
$contact2 = $_POST['contact1'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "userpwd";
$dbname = "dbname";
// Establishing connection with server..
$dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password , $dbname)
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

// Selecting Database 
if (isset($_POST['name1'])) {
//Insert query 
$query = mysqli_query("insert into form_element(name, email, password, contact) values ('$name2', '$email2', '$password2','$contact2')");
echo "Form Submitted succesfully";
}
//connection closed
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

I don't get it work.

Comment: first try something and then ask a question

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Unfortunately, this is not a tutorial site. If you are looking for a tutorial on how to use PHP to process form data, a simple google search will give you many to choose from. If you have some code that you are currently working on and you have a more specific question, then this is the place for that. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then modify your question to include any simplified code you have written and indicate where you are having any problems.

Comment: Check out this page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just edited my code. please have a look. @gmiley

Comment: thank you . @Sachith I just edited my code.

Comment: ok thank you. I will give a try @EmmetArries

Comment: I some of deleted my comments, see below.

Comment: Is the code in the question ALL of the code?

Comment: If not, could you post it all?

Comment: Could you post your file/folder hierarchy too?

Comment: @EmmetArries . The others file are just css and jquery.min.js.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One last thing! Is there anything else this page does besides having a form on it?

Comment: nothing else sir.. thank you for your reply. @EmmetArries

Comment: OK, Hold tight while I work something out!

Comment: sure. :) @EmmetArries

Comment: Still Working! Will be ready soon, sorry for the delay!

Comment: ok no problem @EmmetArries

Comment: Wow, this is taking a long time, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all the `div`'s you had in there before, but you should be able to add them!

This should work once you put in the right username, password and database name in `connection.php`

If this doesn't work or isn't what you wanted, please let me know!

This is also up and running at http://emmetstudios.com/form, if you want to see it in operation.

---

Here's the code, (put it all in the same folder, different files):

connection.php:

```
<?php
function Connect()
{
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "yourusername";
 $dbpass = "yourpassword";
 $dbname = "yourdatabasename";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

 return $conn;
}
?>
```

success.php:

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$name   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$contact   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);

$query = "INSERT into form_element (name,email,password,contact) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $email . "','" . $password . "','" . $contact . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Successful!";

$conn->close();

?>
```

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form" action="success" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="upload">

    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name">          <br><br>

    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">         <br><br>

    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" name="password">      <br><br>

    Phone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="contact">       <br><br>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
    if (name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var email = document.forms["form"]["email"].value;
    if (email == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var password = document.forms["form"]["password"].value;
    if (password == "") {
        alert("Password must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var contact = document.forms["form"]["contact"].value;
    if (contact == "") {
        alert("contact must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works when I combine all php files in one folder. But can I change the index.php into index.html ,and put the index on another place separately from other php files.  can it be possible?

Comment: @J.Jambul Changing `index.php` to `index.html` should work fine. You can move the other `.php` files, if you still put `connection.php` and `success.php` in the same folder (in a different location) it's easy. All you need to do is change the `action="success"` in the html form to `action="success.php"` and add the file path before `success.php`. Let me know if it doesn't work or make sense!